# How can I hook into Visual Studio's debugging infrastructure?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, plugins

On the build side, I have an assembly that extends MSBuild tasks to support compilation and linking with external tools (gcc, et al., as it happens).  I press F7 and my MSBuild tasks get invoked.

Now I want to do the same thing for debugging.  Ultimately, when I press F5, I want gcc (local) to run and connect to gdbserver (on another computer) using some properties I set for debugging (the IP or name of the remote, etc.)

WinGDB and VisualGDB do this (or something like it) so I know it is possible but they have limitations and/or eccentricities that make them hard for me to use as a replacement for my existing build support.  And using them just for debugging is awkward, too (extra, redundant properties to set, etc.).

So, how can I invoke a program of my choice when I press F5?  I found a [fairly old article](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/02/15/the-custom-msbuild-task-cookbook.aspx) that talks about setting an external program as your debugger but can't seem to make that work in VS2010.  In VS2010 I find Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Debugger to Launch but the list doesn't seem extensible.  Is there some plugin architecture to add to that list?

Update: A VSPackage may be the answer. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165789%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says `SVsDebugLaunch` "Allows a VSPackage to support starting a debugger."

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're after. You want to be able to hit F5 in Visual Studio and have it launch a process in an external debugger?

Comment: Yes. In the project's Property Pages, I can see a "Debugger to Launch" item on the "Debugging" tab. I think I want to be able to add an item to the drop down list there. Or maybe there's another way.

Comment: What kind of project is it?

Comment: C for Linux. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: MsBuild has close to nothing to do with debugging. Nor do MsBuild tasks. Please make *clear* what you actually want, can only guess know. Do you want to launch a remote process on linux and debug that from within VS?

Comment: MSBuild tasks seemed the obvious way to extend VS but if that's not the path, I need something else.  Rewrote my question to clarify.